# How to find the sum for customer's multiple payments using Excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hello, 
I am trying to configure a *=if(countif)* code in Excel to calculate the sum for customers of multiple payments. I'm basing their unique value on their Customer# as that's the most unique identifier as some people might have the same name. The code I've entered is having some issues and I don't have a strong experience with using this type of formula. Below is a generic sample and the code.

```
A:Name      B:Customer# C:Paid  D: Sum
Jane Doe    1044        88
Jane Doe    1044        22
Jack Doe    1088        6
Jack Doe    1088        5
Jane Doe    1520        200
Katey Doe   1222        65
Katey Doe   1222        4
Jack Doe    1045        6
Jack Doe    1045        78
Bill Doe    1011        5
```

(I'm unable to post an image yet)

**This is the code I'm trying to use in column D:**
`=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,B1)>1,IF(COUNTIF(B$:B1,B1)=1,=SUM(C:C,C1),=SUM(C:C,C1))"")`

Answer (score 3):

### SUMIF

On cell `D2` enter the formula `=SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,B2,$C$2:$C$11)` and drag down which will create this table

[image]

---

### Pivot Table

A pivot table would be my summary method. This will stop you from having repeated values. Notice that the Sum for each customer is repeated which is not the ideal view. Instead you can try a simple pivot that only requires 3 columns: Name, CSR #, & Paid

[image]

Comment: Thank you, both methods work well for what is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want to use `SUMIF()`

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$11,B2,$C$2:$C$11)
```

Drag down..